# Setting team profile or permission on Frappe ERPNext

Tags: user-roles, erpnext, frappe

I wonder if there is any way to setup the permission for Team on Frappe ERPNext.

Frappe ERPNext only allows to select the "Only if Creator", which means I can only access to the document that I created. However, the information is confidential but it takes a lot while sharing each document to the team members.

I want to setup the profile that a team with about 3 or more people can see each others document (for example Sales Order), while others team cannot.

Please give me some solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi after digging up I found you can use "User Permissions" to limit only the doc that have a "link" to a specific value in a field.

Check out:
https://docs.erpnext.com/docs/user/manual/en/user-permissions

For example in your "Sales Order" you can add a custom field "Team" and limit this instance to only users who have this rule in "user permissions"